# "Jumping footer" issue when div's position is absolute

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have such issue.

I have created separate template's file page-special.php where I have entered such code:

```
<?php
get_header(); 
?>

<style>

#top {
   width: 100%; 
   width: 100vw;
   background-color:#f1f1f1;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   margin: 0 auto;

}

</style>

<div id="top">
   <h2>Responsive Background Images</h2>  

    .... more content here....  

</div>

<?php 

get_footer(); 

?>
```

If I remove `position: absolute` everything looks nice: header + content + footer but my content than boxed in a center (in theme style).

If I add `position: absolute` than content display on the full page width BUT a footer jumps from a bottom of the page till a content part and situated above of it.

How could I make my div being displayed on a full page width with no having issues with footer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the `div` and try if it didn't 
just force the bottom ti be position `relative` but be sure that footer outside of `#top`

```html
?php
get_header(); 
?>

<style>

#top {
   width: 100%; 
   width: 100vw;
   background-color:#f1f1f1;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   margin: 0 auto;

}

</style>

<div id="top">
   <h2>Responsive Background Images</h2>  

    .... more content here....  
</div>

<?php 

get_footer(); 

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for a comment and your support. It is closed for sure, I have just had typo when I wrote a question. It is not engaged with it.